# What is the simpliest way to pseudo-encrypt and decrypt a variable in php?

Tags: php, encryption

I am passing an album id via in url via GET in PHP. I would like to prevent users from trying out random album ids with a basic (doesnt have to be 100% safe) pseudo-encryption so instead of album_id=238 I get a random-looking string. But then I should be able to simply get the real value of that 'encrypted' string and get the values from the database. I know I could use md5 and store an encrypted album id in the database, but this seems like an overkill for my little application. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why is MD5 or any other hash function overkill?

Comment: There's no good reason not to completely encrypt it if you're going to go halfway anyway.

Comment: @JonasKöritz - well, I know what you mean but I would need to change the databse structure, then there is a problem with retreving the actual value in my case and so on. I really need a quick fix and was wondering if php itself offers a simple shuffling function or do I need to write my own..

Comment: For a really dirty solution (there simply is no reason to do this half way) you might use base64

Comment: @JonasKöritz That should do the trick, thanks!

Comment: Whilst it is in the development process, it'll be easier to change around the database structure, than what it would when it's live. It'll be best to do it now whilst you can. Don't be a lazy developer

Comment: @Daryl - I know you're right but...:)

Comment: @Vonder I wonder what else you're being lazy about ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple, **not even half secure**, **totally not encryption** solution you might use base64.

for example `238` will become `MjM4`.

This is by no means encryption but might make it this little tiny bit trickier to guess the album ids.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, I know it is not secure or not even encryption but I have already taken other measures, this is simply for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but UUIDs are great for this with their 122 bits of entropy (for UUIDv4).

Easy to generate, practically impossible to guess.

If you generate a million UUIDs per second, you will have a 1% chance of there being duplicates after 10'000 years.

So if you had `10000 years * 1 million UUID/sec = 10^17` UUIDs already on the system, then the probability of someone guessing one of them is absolutely tiny.